# Regex pick only numbers from end of the string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need a bit of a help with regex, fro example I have these strings:

- "Dovolenka (8)"
- "Bol raz jeden život  26/26"
- "Parížski mohykáni č.1"
- "Vtipnejší vyhráva 1985; Deň tlače,rozhlasu a televízi"

And I need to get the numbers "8", "26", "1", but not the "1985" that's a year not a part number. I got this so far `'/(\d+).?$/'` that works for picking the number but I do not know how to remove the string for `preg_replace()` function, so it only returns the wanted numbers.

Edit: What if i wanted only the strings, so vice versa ?

Comment: [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: How do you distinguish the years from other numbers? Also, `8` is not quite at the _end_ of the string `"Dovolenka (8)"`.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov Well, the last number should be the part number, I can not 100% rely on that unfortunately, but the 99% of strings are that way, which is a great percentage. And the ')' at the end I solved by ".?" or didn't I ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at  [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function, the third parameter is the array of matched items, as you enclose your numbers in brackets, you'll find them there. To be more precise, $matches[1] contains mathcing numbers, $matches[0] contains the whole matched expression.

Comment: It seems to do the trick ! Thanks. Still curious, about the preg_repalce() method if anyone wants to come up with it.

Comment: maybe preg_replace_callback() may be handy, but you need to write a callback function to handle the replacement